# Download RPM on Windows PC then install on Centos server

Tags: centos, centos7, rpm, yum

I'm really stuck in installing services in Centos server. I almost browse all the pages in Google result. I'm a Windows user and very new in Linux environment, so it makes me difficult to understand all the results from Google.

The server doesn't have option to connect to the internet. Based on my research, my only way is to download all the RPM files in a machine with internet then transfer it to my server.

Problem: I cannot find the official package list of YUM so I can download it one by one like the https://bower.io/search/. There's a lot of downloadable files showing if I type in Google "YUM php7 rpm".

Edit: I am currently using YUM because I don't know any other way to install packages in Centos. I only want to install the following :

- php7
- nodejs
- composer
- supervisor
- nginx

I don't have any access to any media. I just remotely access it via putty and Filezilla. But I have root access.

Comment: this is much better suited for serverfault.com, or unix.stackexchange.com, but just as a pointer, you could create a local mirror for your CentOS installation and install software from that local repository. https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/CreateLocalMirror

Comment: Creating a local mirror is a little bit advanced for me. :( I already browse that option. The thing is, i need linux based os connected to the internet to follow the tutorial. my development pc is windows. :(

Comment: Do you want the *entire* list or are you just looking for specific stuff? Is there any reason you can run `yum` on your linux machine directly?

Comment: Do you have access to the OS media from which you install the CentOS

Comment: thanks guys for the response, i have edited my question. i hope i gave u the right information